# Extract iframe src before character

Tags: javascript, jquery, youtube, src

I am selecting this `iframes` src

```
<iframe src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/Y44_kWSoiPc?rel=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

using

```
var youtubesrc = $('iframe[src^="http://www.youtube.com/embed/"]').attr('src');
```

which returns `http://www.youtube.com/embed/Y44_kWSoiPc?rel=0`.

But I only want the src before the `?` *(question mark)* so that in this case it will return `http://www.youtube.com/embed/Y44_kWSoiPc`, which is before the `?`.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the line into:

```
var youtubesrc = $('iframe[src^="http://www.youtube.com/embed/"]').attr('src').split('?')[0];
```

You will split the string into parts separated by `?` and then take 1st part which is everything from the start of the string until `?`.

And if there is no `?` in the string then `split('?')[0]` will contain whole string, so you don't have to check if the URL contains `?`.

Answer (score 1):

```
var youtubesrc = $('iframe[src^="http://www.youtube.com/embed/"]').attr('src');
if (youtubesrc.indexOf('?') > 0)
    youtubesrc = youtubesrc.substr(0, youtubesrc.indexOf('?'));
```